# Window installation issue on boot

Tags: windows, installation, operating-systems, hp-laptop

I have problem to install windows using USB. Initially I tried to install usb it went install step, so in partition allocation page I formated System library director (C Drive) and it show disk former is not supposed. So I tried to restart and start from beginning but my Bootable USB is not loading the is installation even after set boot priority as USB. it's showing "operating system wasn't found. Please remove the unwanted drives" please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: "disk former is not supposed" or "System library director" are not proper English. I understand that English is not your first language, that's okay, but we won't be able to help you without understanding what you're writing about. Try using Google Translate to get more accurate translations. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also adding screenshot/image of the error will be helpful